# PayPal Adaptive Payments ConvertCurrency Request (deprecated API) in Python

Tags: python, paypal, request, paypal-adaptive-payments

I can't find any example on how to make a convertcurrency request using the paypal API in python, can you give me some examples for this simple request?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an existing integration for which you have an Adaptive APP ID? If not, the Adaptive Payments APIs are very old and deprecated, so you would not have permissions to use this, regardless of whether you can find ready-made code samples for Python.